# Can I combine Json.Builder with JsonOutput in groovy? CSV to JSON

Tags: json, csv, groovy

I have to parse csv file (with some modifications) to json in groovy.When I'm trying to execute this code i have a problem with spliting some values.

Content of csv file:

TestKey;Finished;user;status

RWS.PT.001;2020-07-20T23:01:21+02:00;admin;PASS;

RWS.PT.002;2020-07-20T23:02:21+02:00;admin;PASS;

my code in groovy:

```
    import groovy.json.*    
        def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    def root = builder {
    testExecutionKey 'DEMO-303'
    info (
        user: 'admin')
        tests 'rows':'ghgh','uuuuu' 
    }
    print JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(root))
    def csvfile = new File('C:/temp/raportTest.csv').readLines()
    def keys = csvfile[0].split(';')
    def rows = csvfile[1..-1].collect { line ->
        def i = 0, vals = line.split(';')
        keys.inject([:]) { map, key -> map << ["$key": vals[i++]] }
    }
    print JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(rows))
```

my target file should looks like this:

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info" : {
        "user" : "admin"
    },
    "tests" : [
        {
            "testKey" : "RWS.PT.001",
            "finished" : "2020-07-20T23:01:21+02:00",
            "status" : "PASS"
        },
{
            "testKey" : "RWS.PT.002",
            "finished" : "2020-07-20T23:01:21+02:00",
            "status" : "PASS"
        }
     ]
}
```

Now I have:

```
    {
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "rows": "ghgh"
        },
        "uuuuu"
    ]
    }[
    {
        "TestKey": "RWS.PT.001",
        "Finished": "2020-07-20T23:01:21+02:00",
        "user": "admin",
        "status": "PASS"
    },
    {
        "TestKey": "RWS.PT.002",
        "Finished": "2020-07-20T23:02:21+02:00",
        "user": "admin",
        "status": "PASS"
    }
    ]
```

How can I input code from def rows (from JsonOutput) into JsonBuilder (instead of "rows": "ghgh").
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You over-engineered it a bit. You actually don't have to combine anything, just use the JsonBuilder and some Groovy magic:

```
import groovy.json.*

def kindaFile = '''
TestKey;Finished;user;status
RWS.PT.001;2020-07-20T23:01:21+02:00;admin;PASS;
RWS.PT.002;2020-07-20T23:02:21+02:00;admin;PASS;
'''.trim()

def keys
def testList = []
//parse CSV
kindaFile.splitEachLine( /;/ ){ parts ->
  if( !keys )
    keys = parts
  else{
    def test = [:]
    parts.eachWithIndex{ val, ix -> test[ keys[ ix ] ] = val }
    testList << test
  }
}

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder {
  testExecutionKey 'DEMO-303'
  info user: 'admin'
  tests testList
}

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(root))
```

prints

```
{
    "testExecutionKey": "DEMO-303",
    "info": {
        "user": "admin"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "TestKey": "RWS.PT.001",
            "Finished": "2020-07-20T23:01:21+02:00",
            "user": "admin",
            "status": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "TestKey": "RWS.PT.002",
            "Finished": "2020-07-20T23:02:21+02:00",
            "user": "admin",
            "status": "PASS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. Now I have a problem only with lack of UTF-8 encoding. Do you know how to add proper encoding? (I think problem is with JsonOutput)

Comment: I suppose you have the input file in a strange (non-UTF-8) format? Share a piece of your file so I can try it out

Comment: for example :

testKey;status
PT.49004 Wyszukanie skierowań ;PASS
PT.43000 Wyszukanie słów ;PASS

Comment: this is not really a "lack" of encoding, it's a so-called unicode escaping in JSON format. If you parse back the output, it will be proper UTF-8

Comment: @injecter maybe you will know how to parse CSV to JSON from 2 CSV Files?